# How to use custom brushes in Gimp?

Tags: gimp, brush

I found a custom brushes menu in Gimp but I don't know how to use them. I'd like to draw some stars on a background. How can I create a brush to do this?

Comment: there's a full tutorial for custom brushes on https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Custom_Brushes/ , have you at least tried that?

Answer (score 1):

Basically you make up your own image, and export it as a .GBR file, in a directory that you'll find in Edit>Preferences>Folders>Brushes.

- If the brush image is grayscale (as in Image>Mode>Grayscale), then it is considered an opacity mask, the white is transparent and the black is replaced by the foreground color.
- If the image is RGB then it is used as is. For quick test you can copy your image to the clipboard, and use the "clipboard" brush (always the first in the list).

If you just want a geometric star, they you can create a "parametric" brush:

- open the brushes list,
- hit the "New brush icon" to start the editor
- pick the square or diamond shapes
- adjust spikes to taste
- adjust aspect ratio to taste

Comment: Also, note  the option of "paste as new brush" - that is a shortcut for "save the clipboard contents as .gbr file on the correct folder"